# Let the hover text for the blog link at the page bottom always show the latest entry's age

Tags: feature-request, usability, blog, tooltips, news

I like the `new` button that now appears when a new blog entry is there, and it has a hover text stating the age of this new entry. But why not display that age for the blog link itself as well so one can check that information even when the `new` button is absent?

Comment: You want them to integrate wordpress blog's data to the site?

Comment: @YOU: sorry, I don't get what you mean here. I just mean to change the link to the SO blog at the bottom of each page so that it has the same hover text that the button "new" already provides, just in a more permanent way since the "new" button vanishes after some time if no new entry appeared

Comment: Sorry Tobias, I think I am assuming something wrong.